# Router periodically stops working (partially)

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

My home network consists of two Linksys wireless routers, let's call them A and B, and a switch, which provides ethernet connectivity to wired ports throughout the house. The internet cable connects to router A, which in turn connects to the switch to provide wired internet to the house. Router B is plugged in to some port in the house and is in bridge mode, to extend the wireless coverage. When I initially set this up, it worked great, you could walk around the house with a laptop and it'd seamlessly switch channels as needed to get the best wireless connection.

After about a month, however, problems emerged. (This coincided with my roommate moving in, adding additional wireless devices.) Every so often (on the order of days), router A will stop working, but only partially, in the following way. It will not accept wireless connections. If you navigate to its IP address in a browser (from a wired connection), it returns an HTTP error 500. However, the internet still works if you connect through a wired port or wirelessly through router B. The situation can be fixed by turning router A off and on, and sometimes resolves itself after a certain amount of time.

I'm a bit ignorant of networking, so I don't have a clue what the problem could be, and even if I did I wouldn't know how to debug since the problem happens rarely and at random. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone had a suggestion!

Comment: I've seen routers act like that if they're overloaded, and you have the stock firmware - are you guys running torrents ?

Comment: Could it be your router couldn't handle that much of devices/sessions? How frequent you reboot your wireless router?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - No torrents. I'd be very surprised if the router is overloaded, we're not doing anything serious.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov - We typically have 3 devices on at a time, so that shouldn't be a problem. We only reboot the router when it stops working, every few days.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are having a conflict with your roommate's router.  Log into your router and look for the wireless channel it is using.  It will be a number from 1-11 or it might be set to something like Auto which is probably the default.  You can set both you routers to specific channels and also set your roommate's router to a specific channel.  In this way each router will have a different channel and not conflict.  There is the issue though you might have similar interference from neighbors.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear: my roommate did not bring a new router. I just meant the problems began around the time they came and started using their laptop and phone. The two routers are on channels 1 and 11, so I don't think that's the problem.